# How can I get all the exercises for a topic (e.g., math) and all its subtopics from the khanacademy api?

Tags: khan-academy

Khan Academy's API Explorer has an [exercises section](http://api-explorer.khanacademy.org/group/api/v1/exercises) that mentions filtering by tags, but the [url with math tag applied](http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/exercises?tags=math) returns nothing.

The generic exercise objects don't contain the topic they're in.  My guess is that there's an id to join on somewhere in the topictree/exercises json objects, but I don't know an efficient way to find it.

Here are the raw [exercises json](http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/exercises) and raw [topictree json](http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree) (note, the second one is huge, and contains many topics other than math).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a nice way to return exercises from just a subtree of the topictree (e.g. just math). Tags are a different concept, and there isn't a tag common to everything in math. Probably your best bet is to load the full topictree with just Exercises (and Topics) and work from there:

`http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree?kind=Exercise`

If you need to reference this structure repeatedly, it probably makes sense to download and filter it ahead of time, and maybe re-fetch it from time to time to account for changes to Khan Academy content. But it depends on your exact use case.

Generally, any content item can be referenced by `content_id` (sometimes just called `id`) or by `slug`, but unfortunately, the naming and usage aren't consistent everywhere.

Comment: Thanks Alan.  While Jannie's answer was correct and included yours, I accepted yours because it got me exactly what I needed without any parts that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to get all the exercises:

```
http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/exercises
http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree?kind=Exercise
```

I'm not sure what's the difference between these two - I don't use them.
I prefer to fetch the data for the individual topic nodes as follows:

```
http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topic/%s
http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topic/%s/exercises
http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topic/%s/videos
```

where %s is the "node_slug" property for each topic. The root of the tree is just "root". The first one will give you the topic details and a list of sub-items in the "child_data" array. Use the "id" properties of each sub-topic in this array to look up its details in the "children" array having "internal_id" equal to "id". There you get the "node_slug" to for the next API call for that sub-topic. The "child_data" array has all the sub-items in the order that they appear on the website when you're working with the missions.

I cache these responses so that I don't have to download everything every time.

Comment: Thanks Jannie. I'm unsure how [topic/algebra/exercises](http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topic/algebra/exercises) works for you. It returns an empty array for me.

[topictree?kind=Exercise](http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree?kind=Exercise) did return data to join by, but lacked exercise data like seconds_per_fast_problem.

[exercises](http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topic/algebra/exercises) returned an array joinable on IDs, urls, node_slug, and other properties. I ultimately matched on relative_url as a tradeoff between brevity and ease for me to grok while working with the data.

Comment: @Adam. You have to traverse the tree as I explained in my answer. Just use api/v1/topic/algebra to get the sub-topics under Algebra. They're in the "child_data" and "children" entries. Now do the same for each of these. Continue like that until you get the sub-topics that actually contain exercises (and videos). Then use the api/v1/topic/%s/exercises format for each of these to get the exercises. For the videos use api/v1/topic/%s/videos.

Comment: How do you actually use these exercise entries? The questions from the exercise aren't listed

Comment: I don't use the exercises via my app - I just wanted to explore the API and currently it only uses the API calls that don't require authorization. My app is not working properly at the moment - it doesn't handle some newer topics correctly - and I haven't really used it for a long time.